# CreateWindowsEx fails when creating window

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I am new to win32 API GUI programming in C++. When the program is compiled and executed, It always fails at `CreateWindowsEx`. Sorry but this only what I can explain at this moment.

Aside from that, It passes the window registration, which is good. But from the time Windows Creation executed, it always return NULL.

Here's my C++ code:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow){
  //MessageBox(NULL, "Hello ", " H", MB_OK);
  WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
  //memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
  //wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProcedure; /* This is where we will send messages to */
    wc.hInstance     = hInst;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    /* White, COLOR_WINDOW is just a #define for a system color, try Ctrl+Clicking it */
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* Load a standard icon */
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* use the name "A" to use the project icon */

  if(! RegisterClassEx(&wc) ){
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error 1", " H", MB_OK);
    return -1;
  }

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"WindowClass","Caption",WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
        640, /* width */
        480, /* height */
        NULL,NULL,hInst,NULL);
  //returns 0x0 
  //return GetLastError();
  if( hwnd == NULL){
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error 2", " H", MB_OK);
    return GetLastError();
  }
  MSG msg = {0};

  while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) ){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
  switch(msg){
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  default:
    return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Please approach in the level of a novice, so it easy for me to understand what should be done.

Comment: As per the docs: "*To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*"

Comment: @AlexF changed to "WindowClass" but still fail :-(

Comment: @AlexF compiled but still does not work

Comment: @AlexF actually tried what @AlexK said. Replaced `return -1` with `return GetLastError()`, but return 0x0 (ERROR_SUCCESS)

Comment: @AlexF I tried it but it still returns 0x0 (Error success)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the `CreatewindowEx` fails is because of `DefWindowProcW` should be `DefWindowProc`.

`DefwindowProcW` is used with `CreateWindowW`, but since it is using `CreateWindowEx`, `DefWindowProc` should be the correct one to use.

Comment: To elaborate - this code is clearly being compiled for ANSI and not Unicode, so `CreateWindowEx()` is calling the ANSI version `CreateWindowExA()`, but the `WindowProcedure()` is calling the Unicode `DefWindowProcW()`, which is a mismatch. Switching to `DefWindowProc()` will call the ANSI version `DefWindowProcA()`

Comment: It's not the call to `CreateWindowEx` that controls whether the window procedure needs to forward to `DefWindowProcA` or `DefWindowProcW`. It's the call to `RegisterClassExA` or `RegisterClassExW` that establishes whether [IsWindowUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowunicode) returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.